# Uninstall of VS2010 RC gets stuck on uninstall of Crystal Reports templates for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

The progress bar is stuck at 100%.

Any suggestions for the best/cleanest way torwards a healthy install of VS2010 Final Release?

I have this problem all the time with the MS Installer (MSIEXEC.exe/setup.exe). Previously, reinstalling the MS Installer didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reboot, you will be able to the Control Panel and continue the uninstall from where it left off.